# When I create a new form in mvc that time the id value is showing 0

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, wcf, entity-framework-6

I am Trying to Create a CRUD operations using mvc and wcf and entity framework
 When I try to add a new form does not work and no error message appears.
But the edit and delete operations are working fine. Only it's not creating the new form that time the id value is 0 it's not getting an ID value.
I am trying more times.but it's not getting proper solutions. So Give me one Solution

I published the project on public website if you want to check.
Link: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=40899801495052398066

The database name is "mydemo"

Thanks,
Pari

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo]. [Product] (
     [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
     [Name] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
     [Price] MONEY NULL,
     [Quantity] INT NULL,
     [CreationDate] DATE NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your EDMX model `Id`'s `Store Generated Pattern` is not set to `Identity`.

but since your sql query for creating Table has Identity for Id column, I suggest removing your EDMX and create it again.

Comment: when i tried to set the identity in Generated pattern in edmx but it's not working I dn't know why its not working any another idea

Comment: delete your EDMX file completely and add it again

Comment: it's Working Fine.Thanks a lot.. Dude.

Answer (score 0):

Id column in database should be primary key. If a column is identity and is not primary key, Its value is showing 0.